# When I run my code it shows some errors on terminal. Could any can tell me what is the error stands for? How can I debug it?

Tags: c

Errors:

```
Test isPower2(0[0x0]) failed.
Gives 1[0x1].  Should be 0[0x0]
```

Code:

```c
int isPower2(int x) {

    int nonNega = (x>>31);

    int result = !((x & (x-1)) ^ nonNega);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `isPower2(0)` returns true (1) but 0 is not a power of 2. So the expected result would be false (0).